# Removing burnt olive oil from an enamelled cast iron pan and a non-stick marble pan?

Tags: cleaning

I was wondering what the best way to remove this burnt on olive oil is? These are both pretty new pans. I've heard of using an oven cleaner for the cast iron pan but I'm unsure if it will ruin the enamel coating. I have no idea what to do for the marble effect frying pan.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Enamelled cast iron pan]
[image: Marble non-stick frying pan]

Comment: For a cast iron pan, burnt oil is also known as 'seasoning'.  If it's not flaking off, you might be able to scrape down any high spots and add a few more layers of seasoning to even it out.

Comment: @Joe Enamel is supposed to replace the need for seasoning on a cast iron pan. I've never heard of anybody seasoning an enameled pan.

Comment: @rumtscho : doh.  I somehow read that as the two pans being cast iron & enameled cast iron.  Yeah, that's not the way to go for enameled.  or non-stick.

Answer (score 1):

Lodge has a pretty extensive, [instructions](http://www.lodgemfg.com/use-and-care/caring-for-your-lodge-enameled-cookware) for usage and caring for enamel cast iron pans.

In short the advice is as follows:

1. Hand washing with warm soapy water and a nylon Scrub Brush is recommended to preserve the cookware’s original appearance. Citrus juices and citrus-based cleaners (including some dishwasher detergents) should not be used, as they can dull the exterior gloss.
2. If necessary, use nylon pads or scrapers to remove food residue; metal pads or utensils will scratch or chip porcelain.
3. Remove slight stains by rubbing with dampened cloth and commercial Enamel Cleaner product or other ceramic cleaner according to directions on bottle.
4. For persistent stains, soak interior of the cookware for 2 to 3 hours with a mixture of 3 tablespoons of household bleach per quart of water.
5. To remove stubborn baked on food, bring to a boil 2 cups of water and 4 tablespoons of baking soda. Boil for a few minutes then use a Pan Scraper to loosen food.